# Why pre-increment does not work with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have the following functional component

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const test = () => {
    setCount(++count);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={test}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

when i click on the `Click me` button, it does not work - notice that i am using pre-increment here
`++count`

but when i do the same thing with `increment only`

`setCount(count++)`

then it works.

Why it is not working with pre-increment ?

Comment: But `count` is a `const` declaration. Should fail anyway with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre or Post increment, either way is the wrong way to increment a counter in React as both mutate state. State is also declared `const`, so it can't be updated anyway.

```js
const count = 0;

++count; // error

console.log(count);
```

Use a functional state update.

```
setCount(c => c + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Drew.But if i use - let instead of const then i will have problems again with the increment. Why pre and post increment are making problems ? We are mutating state here but it is of value type, not a reference type so we don't need a copy of it. Can you please explain ?

Comment: @sdsd It's just one of the Commandments of React: "Thou shalt not mutate state", we just don't do it as there could be unintended side-effects/consequences. I agree that in this specific example, mutating the state is fairly benign, but it *is still a mutation* and should be avoided. Do you have a working example where the post-increment works? I've copied your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-pre-increment-does-not-work-with-setstate-k2yn2) and the pre-increment "works", but the post-incrememt doens't, which shows the issue of unintended state mutation.

Comment: Yes, my mistake was that  i used const... with let post increment will not work either. Thank you for your answer. I accepted